# Intraday volatility measures in comparison to end of day measurement

Tags: volatility, reference-request, intraday

I'm experimenting with Parkinson's Number and the Garman-Klass estimator I'm wondering what the appropriate number of days to sample over, is the number over 1-day useful at all, or should one take it over a week or more at a time?

Also with the Parkinson Number, Taleb in Dynamic Hedging uses 1.67 ratio to determine whether it's more/less volatile, does anyone know if there's a theoretical basis for that?

And lastly, if there's any similar reference for the GK estimator?

(Am reading Pages 101 onwards in Dynamic Hedging if anyone owns a copy of that)

Thank you!

Comment: who are the authors of dynamic hedging

Comment: Nassim Nicolas Taleb

Comment: parkinsons 1.67 might be explained as a footnote or endnotes to the chapter it's mentioned in. If not referenced directly, follow the closest source to the sentence in the list of references at the back of the chapter or book.

Comment: related question https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/43794/does-your-parkinson-volatility-ratio-work-as-taleb-explained